# Qt firstVisibleBlock const is protected error

Tags: c++, qt

I am implementing a Code Editor into a program I am making following this tutorial
[enter link description here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-codeeditor.html)

I am getting stuck on the "lineNumberPaintEvent" method. This is what I have

```
void LineNumbers::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.fillRect(event->rect(), NUMBER_LINE_COLOR);

    QTextBlock block    = parent->armaEdit->firstVisibleBlock();
    int blockNumber     = block.blockNumber();
}
```

where "armaEdit" is a QPlainTextEdit widget in another class.
When I attempt to run this, I get the following error:

```
error: 'QTextBlock QPlainTextEdit::firstVisibleBlock() const' is protected
```

I have not come across this error yet, and I have no clue what is means, or what I am doing wrong.  May someone please point out my error?

Comment: Does your class inherit from QPlainTextEdit?

Answer (score 3):

A protected method is one that the author of the class has marked with the "protected" keyword.  It is only accessible to subclasses of the class (i.e. to code in a subclass of QPlainTextEdit, in this case).

Usually this is an indication that you shouldn't call that method, as it wasn't intended for use by any code other than QPlainTextEdit or its subclasses.

If you really need to call it, though, you could create a subclass of QPlainTextEdit, and call firstVisibleBlock() from within a method of that subclass.